# How to know where to look for media directories on android phone?

Tags: android, filesystems, android-gallery, android-storage

I am working on a Gallery app which requires knowing where to look within the user's android device for images/videos. Currently, I am brute forcing it by going all the way up to the root directory, looking specifically for directories starting with "storage" and "sdcard" and searching each and every sub folder for files containing the proper extension.

There must be a better way to find media directories within the Android file system, no? Can anyone suggest any alternatives?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there is a way to find all media directories, you'll have to scan each folder.
But you can skip folders which has `.nomedia` file, This will save some scanning time.